# Preposition choice - Project [in/at/for] my company

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Is this acceptable to say the following:

> I am working on a project in my company

Will 'for' keep the same meaning?

How about 'at'?

Is there any rule of thumb to make such choices more easily?

I looked at [Working in / for / at?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5411/working-in-for-at)  but I have a feeling that my case is slightly different. Because here we have an additional noun before "company". I understand that saying: "I work at XYZ" is preferred but what if we have something else coming before? If somebody is working on a project, is he working for or at company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am working for a project in my company

This makes it sound like the project is your employer, or somehwat like that you are attempting to win a project for your company.

> I am working on a project in my company

This is idiomatic.

You wouldn't work *at* a project unless the project was a place.

It's easiest if you just think of *work on X* as a phrasal verb that means "to perform work upon X and/or try to advance X to a state of completion."

Comment: Does this sound idiomatic to everyone? "In my company" has a military ring to me, whereas "at my company" or "for my company" sound corporate.