# "The first day I worked at that company" vs. "The first day I worked for that company"

Tags: prepositions

I am aware that when describing the company, I could say "the company I worked **for**", how do I do when I am referring to the time?

I was telling a story about the company I worked for, when referring the day I am on board, should I say

> "The first day I worked **at** that company"

or

> "The first day I worked **for** that company"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Working in / for / at?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5411/working-in-for-at)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are fine.

It would be possible to work *for* a company without working *at* a company.  For example if you were hired as a freelance worker to work at home or from another office.

Saying "at" means the location where you are working, "for" is about the purpose or benefit. If you are working at a company, it would generally be assumed that you are working for the company too.