# How to correctly use 'on', 'in' and 'at'?

Tags: prepositions, in-on-at

I've researched a bit about the use of these prepositions, but 99% of what I found refer to the use with time and place, but that's not what I need. I've read once that 'on' is used when you're 'on top' of something and 'in' when you're 'inside of something', but that doesn't apply to everything, take this phrase for example: I work **in/on/at** a company.

What would be the correct word **in**(is this the correct one?) this case? Why? Is there a rule of when to use each one?

My native language is Brazilian portuguese.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Working in / for / at?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5411/working-in-for-at)

Comment: The shortest words in English are the ones that are the most difficult to explain with rules. Sometimes you just have to memorize how they are used. You might find [this question about “in the park” and “at the park”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/40439/9161) helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond the official literal meanings of in/on/at that you mention, you're going to find prepositions in English are commonly part of *idiomatic expressions*. Idiomatic expressions have no set rule and you just have to learn them over time. Also, this is super helpful that @ColleenV mentions: [Should I say "She is in the park" or "She is at the park"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40439/should-i-say-she-is-in-the-park-or-she-is-at-the-park)

I would say the following for example:

- I work **in** finance. (the field of the career you have chosen)
- I work **at/for** a large bank in New York
  City. (emphasis on the job)
- I work **in** a large bank in New York City.
  (emphasis on the building)
- I've been working **on** an IPO for
  Bumble. (emphasis on the specific work you've been doing at the company)

They just *feel* right to me and it's hard for me to explain why beyond that.