# What prepositions should I use when talking about being a member of an organization and doing something?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

What prepositions should I use when talking about being a member of an organization and doing something?

**Example 1:**

I play tennis well because when I was a high school student, I played tennis for a year **in/at/on** the school tennis club.

Should I use "in" or "at" or "on"?

**Example 2:**

I have been playing the guitar for 3 years **in/at/on** a rock band.

Should I use "in" or "at" or "on"?

**Example 3:**

I have been doing volunteer work for 3 years **in/at/on** a non-profit organization.

Should I use "in" or "at" or "on"?

**Example 4:**

I have been managing projects and developing software for 3 years **in/at/on** a tech company.

Should I use "in" or "at" or "on"?

Comment: Example 4 is a duplicate of this question about [working + PREP](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/5411/41273)

Comment: as a member of the school's tennis club. Otherwise, in an organization, in a club, in a rock band, on a team.

Answer (score 1):

Use **in** if you mean 'as a member of' and **at** for 'at the premises of'. So (2) definitely needs **in**, but (1) could be either (if the tennis club had its own courts).

With reference to an organisation or company, I would suggest **at** or **for.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If the prepositions are used correctly in examples 1-4, do the sentences sound natural and correct?

Comment: I think a British speaker would say "when I was at [high] school", and in the last three "for three years" would normally be at the end of the sentence.