# A career in, at, or with a corporation?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which preposition fits best between 'career' and 'corporation'?

> This business course will help you advance a career **with/in/at** a
> corporation.

I already had a look at [this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5411/working-in-for-at), but I believe it refers to a slightly different situation. The addition of a noun, i.e. 'career', before the word 'company' (or 'corporation') might change the rules.

I ran some google searches but I got very few results for each case, so I was wondering if perhaps I should rephrase the sentence in a different way.

Comment: I would actually be tempted to say "within", to help resolve the tension between talking about a career and talking about a single organization.

Comment: We actually say: This business course will help you advance your corporate career. corporate career collocates much better than career in/with/at a corporation.

Answer (score 1):

Generally one doesn't have a career *with*, *in*, or *at* a specific corporation.
Those words would be used more generically:

- a career *in* medicine (a large field with many possible jobs and locations).
- a career *with* great financial rewards (an attribute of the job).
- a career *at* McDonald's (humour indicating a life-long low paying job).

For a specific employer, it would be better to say:

- a career *within* Google (the specific company is more important than the specific job).